# Cumulative product of independent random variables with a stopping time

Tags: probability, stopping-times, time-series

Suppose $X_1,X_2, \dots, X_N$ are i.i.d. random variables with $\mathbb{E}[X_1]=\mu\neq 0$. 
Extending the analysis for Wald's equation to where $\tau$ is a stopping time gives their partial sum subject to a stopping time $\tau$ to be
$$
\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i=1}^{\tau} X_i] = \mathbb{E}[\sum_{i=1}^{\tau} \mathbb{E}[X_1]] = \mathbb{E}[\sum_{i=1}^{\tau} \mu].
$$
I am interested in the partial product 
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{\tau} X_i,
$$
where $\{\tau=i\}$ is dependent on $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_i$ and the empty product equals one. Ruben [states](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/theorem-on-the-cumulative-product-of-independent-random-variables/C62FFBCCCC52791F971C671EA004EA93) that such a partial product satisfies
$$
\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^{\tau} X_i\mu^{-\tau}] = 1.
$$
Can we say anything more about the properties of $\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^{\tau} X_i]$? Alternatively, if we knew that $\mu>1$, can we say that
$$
\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^{\tau} X_i] > 1?
$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what an empty product is defined to be, but let's assume an empty product is just $1$. I'm also assuming that the $X_i$ are independent of $\tau$, which is needed for Wald's formula anyway. In that case, we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^{\tau} X_i]&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Pr[\tau = n]\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^{n} X_i\vert \tau = n ]\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Pr[\tau = n] \mu^n\\
&=\Pr[\tau=0]+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Pr[\tau=n]\mu^n\\
&>\Pr[\tau=0]+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Pr[\tau=n]\\
&=1,
\end{align}
where the last inequality follows from the assumption $\mu>1$.

Comment: I did mean $\tau$ is dependent on $X_i$'s. I have updated the question and corrected some of the equations to reflect that.